# Disable a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a normal rails collection_select and select drop downs in my form. I want to disable any more selections in this drop down.

```
= f.collection_select :genre, DecodeConstant::PROJECT_TYP_DD, :id, :display_value, :html_options => { :disabled => @project.status == "RS_A" }

= f.select :currency_code, options_for_select([['Indian Rupee', 'INR'], ['United States Dollar', 'USD']]), :disabled => @project.status == "RS_A"
```

Both of these are not disabling the dropdown. Any suggestions?

Comment: I posted an answer, but it would help a lot if you could post the HTML output for the attempts above.

Comment: Surprisingly HTML o/p for all is the same <select data-validate="true" id="project_genre" name="project[genre]">
<option value="PG_U">Impact per donation (preferred)</option>
<option value="PG_C" selected="selected">Corpus Fund</option>
</select>

Comment: I think this disabled option is to disable OPTIONS and not the whole drop down itself. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f.collection_select :genre, DecodeConstant::PROJECT_TYP_DD, :id, :display_value, {}, { :disabled => @project.status == "RS_A" }
```

Comment: Just looked at the docs, you have to pass it an empty options hash. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
f.collection_select :genre, DecodeConstant::PROJECT_TYP_DD, :id, :display_value, {}, { :disabled => true }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f.collection_select :genre, DecodeConstant::PROJECT_TYP_DD, :id, :display_value, { disabled: lambda{|values| values }}, prompt: true
```